# How can i "merge" rows groupby having same values in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

[link to table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh7qF.jpg)

The name of my dataframe is df.

I want to **combine** the rows having the **same Borough** and **same PostalCode** with **Neighborhood** separated by commas. But I'm not able to get it. Can anyone please help me with it?

Comment: Pleas do not post images of data frame/code here. Try to provide a minimal reproducible code/data here.

Answer (score 2):

you have to first group by the two first column and then apply a transform for joining the result.

```
df['Neighborhood ']= df.groupby(['PostalCode ','Borough'])['Neighboudhood'].transform(lambda x: ','.join(x))
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
df = df.groupby(['PostalCode','Borough'])['Neighbourhood'].agg(','.join)
```

output sample for the two rows:

```
CR0  Croydon    Addington,Addiscombe
```